# All Documents converted to .vvv extension (TeslaCrypt)

Tags: malware, virus

I've found something strange with my employee document, it turns out that all files including document are being encrypted with ".vvv" extension. What I've found so far that it's called TeslaCrypt, it convert all my files to .vvv, even I rename it back to the right extension, it says that file already modified, so I can't open the files anymore. Please help, we cannot work until that document can be oppened. I can't tag this to "TeslaCrpyt" so if anyone can help me tagged it, it would be great.

[image]

content on how to recover :

```
What happened to your files ?
All of your files were protected by a strong encryption with RSA-4096.
More information about the encryption keys using RSA-4096 can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

What does this mean ?
This means that the structure and data within your files have been irrevocably changed, you will not be able to work with them, read them or see them,
it is the same thing as losing them forever, but with our help, you can restore them.

111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
How did this happen ?
---Specially for your PC was generated personal RSA-4096 KEY, both public and private.
---ALL YOUR FILES were encrypted with the public key, which has been transferred to your computer via the Internet.
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Decrypting of your files is only possible with the help of the private key and decrypt program, which is on our secret server.

What do I do ?
So, there are two ways you can choose: wait for a miracle and get your price doubled, or start obtaining BTC NOW, and restore your data easy way.
If You have really valuable data, you better not waste your time, because there is no other way to get your files, except make a payment.

For more specific instructions, please visit your personal home page, there are a few different addresses pointing to your page below:
1. http://vr6g2curb2kcidou.encpayment23.com/E03029AB7D9A9D38
2. http://vr6g2curb2kcidou.expay34.com/E03029AB7D9A9D38
3. http://psbc532jm8c.hsh73cu37n1.net/E03029AB7D9A9D38
4. https://vr6g2curb2kcidou.onion.to/E03029AB7D9A9D38 

If for some reasons the addresses are not available, follow these steps:
1. Download and install tor-browser: http://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en 
2. After a successful installation, run the browser and wait for initialization.
3. Type in the address bar: vr6g2curb2kcidou.onion/E03029AB7D9A9D38 
4. Follow the instructions on the site.

IMPORTANT INFORMATION:
Your personal pages:
http://vr6g2curb2kcidou.encpayment23.com/E03029AB7D9A9D38
http://vr6g2curb2kcidou.expay34.com/E03029AB7D9A9D38
http://psbc532jm8c.hsh73cu37n1.net/E03029AB7D9A9D38 
https://vr6g2curb2kcidou.onion.to/E03029AB7D9A9D38  
Your personal page (using TOR-Browser): vr6g2curb2kcidou.onion/E03029AB7D9A9D38 
Your personal identification number (if you open the site (or TOR-Browser's) directly): E03029AB7D9A9D38
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 1):

I've published a decryption tool on GitHub: https://github.com/googulator/teslacrack

This tool cryptographically breaks the encryption scheme of TeslaCrypt, and so doesn't require a saved master key. However, it's quite computationally intensive, so preferably use a fast computer, and even then, expect to wait up to a week for it to recover your key (although most keys can be found in just a few hours). Also, it's more of a PoC than a user-friendly turnkey decryptor, so you will need to do many things by hand.

Comment: The number being factored is NOT an RSA key, that's the point. It's a 512-bit number with lots of factors, one of which is the session key.

Answer (score 1):

I got hit by TeslaCrypt and all of the solutions (Cisco's Decrypt Tool, Shadow Explorer) did not work for me. Unrelated, I was sniffing around some articles on Ubuntu and found BloodDolly's Tesla Decrypter tool that actually work and my files are being restored as I write this. So just wanted to share since it didn't come up in any of my earlier searches.

It's a handful a steps,...I had no problems whatsoever with the process. Apparently this won't work for the most recent strain,...I had .vvv and had to factor primes with Yafu,...but the documentation and the software is pretty thorough and easy to follow. Took me 15-20 minutes from start to finish.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/576600/tesladecoder-released-to-decrypt-exx-ezz-ecc-files-encrypted-by-teslacrypt/

Anyway, hope this helps some folks.

Comment: Same here, I ran `TeslaDecoder.exe` and got all the files back.  Just click `"Set key"` in the app and choose the file extensions you have been renamed to, and the app will automatically fill in the key, then you can decrypt any folder of files. `TeslaDecoder can now decrypt all variants of TeslaCrypt 3.x and 4.x. This includes encrypted file extensions: .micro, .xxx, .ttt, .mp3, and encrypted files that were not renamed.`